# Success callback function called on failure. Possible bug?

Tags: lua, callback, esp8266, nodemcu, ntp

I'm working on a little project, using an ESP8266 with NodeMCU and Lua. I suspect I've found a bug, but since I'm new to Lua (and the other two too!), I'm hoping for some help in confirming if I'm right, or if I've missed something (more likely!).

The NodeMCU firmware contains a built-in SNTP client module which updates the synchronised time to a system clock (rtctime module). The success callback function seems to get called when (or possibly before) the NTP sync fails. This happens for example if the wifi is not connected, or sometimes on the first sync attempt after boot (with wifi connected). According to the doco, rtctime.get() returns zero if current time is not available; this is the result I get, further showing that the NTP sync hasn't been successful. I can't work out why the success function is being called at this point, in advance of, or instead of the failure function (as I would have expected).

The sntp module I'm referring to is here - unfortunately, the C source code was a bit over my head: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/sntp/

My (minimal) code:

```
-- Define callback function for ntp sync success
function ntpSyncSuccess (sec, usec, server, info)
    print('SNTP time sync successful!')
    print("rtctime.get() returns: ", rtctime.get())
end

-- Configure and start NTP time sync with auto repeat enabled
sntp.sync("0.au.pool.ntp.org",
    ntpSyncSuccess(sec, usec, server, info),   --success callback
    function()          -- error callback
        print('SNTP time sync failed!')
    end,
    1 -- enable autorepeat (SNTP sync every 1000 seconds (~17 min))
)
```

Serial output result when I boot the device and run the code (Note the 2nd and 3rd last lines):

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 11592951b90707cdcb6d751876170bf4da82850d
    SSL: false
    modules: cron,file,gpio,i2c,net,node,rotary,rtctime,sntp,struct,tmr,uart,wifi
 build created on 2019-01-16 03:11
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(6ab97e9)
lua: cannot open init.lua
> print(uart.setup(0, 115200, 8, 0, 1, 1 ))
115200
> dofile("ntpTest.lua")
SNTP time sync successful!
rtctime.get() returns:  0   0   0
> SNTP time sync failed!
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring. Perhaps no obvious issues with what I'd written then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that we can "close" this Q here (once you accept the answer). It has to be a function reference rather than a function invocation.

```
sntp.sync("0.au.pool.ntp.org",
    ntpSyncSuccess,     -- no (), no parameters
    function()          -- error callback
```

Comment: Thanks, tested the changed code and it works. I've at least learnt something here.